# "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" while slicing array

Tags: python, opencv

```
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    ret , prev_frame = cap.read()
    count = 0
    while ret:
        ret , curr_frame = cap.read()
        a1 = curr_frame[:int(h/2-1),:int(w/2-1)]
```

Error:

```
a1 = curr_frame[:int(h/2-1), :int(w/2-1)]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Hi Linda, please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask). Also read [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to test your cap.read() statement.  It is obviously coming back with a `none` result.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    ret , prev_frame = cap.read()
    count = 0
    while ret:
        ret , curr_frame = cap.read() or []
        a1 = curr_frame[:int(h/2-1),:int(w/2-1)]
```